# Correct status code for database server file that's not found?

Tags: php, httpresponse, http-status-codes

I'm implementing a database into my website and learning about http status codes. I'm trying to implement solutions to any problems that may arise from requests and I thought about when connecting to a database to update or query it, what would the correct status code be if the file does not exist on the server side (it may have been taken down temporarily to stop any data being transferred?). I would be implementing a custom message to the user to inform them anyways but was wondering what the 'correct' status code would be for this response? I have narrowed it down to 404 (file not found) or 503 (service not available) or another that I'm not aware of?

**PHP code if it helps**

```
try {
    if (!file_exists("dbConn.php")) {
        throw new Exception("File Not Found");
    } else {
        require_once("dbConn.php");
        $dbConn = getConnection();
    }
    // other code
} catch (Exception $e) {
    if ($e->getMessage() == "Bad Request") {
        http_response_code(400); // This is for an exception thrown in 'other code' (not displayed)
    } else {
        // http_response_code(404) or http_response_code(503) or other?
    }
}
```

Comment: If the file does not exist, then a 404 would be appropriate. It's a file, not a service.

Comment: @aynber Thank you for clarifying, I was a bit confused as 4xx codes are listed under client errors and thought this would be a server issue as it doesn't exist on the web server. Also, the accompanying code to this database code is to register users to my website which is why I thought it could be a service unavailable error

Comment: 404 would indicate that the resource being requested via HTTP was not found (and therefore shouldn't be requested again later).  Is that semantically what's happening here?  It sounds like they requested the correct resource, but the server-side logic is currently failing.  That is, it's not the user's responsibility to know or care anything about the database.  All they're doing is making a request to a resource.  That resource is internally failing.  503 seems appropriate to me.  Maybe even 500.  Something 5xx at least, because *the request itself* was correct.

Comment: As an aside, this appears to be a poor use of exceptions.  `if (!file_exists("dbConn.php"))` is already a logical condition you can examine and respond to.  Throwing an exception just to respond to it somewhere else is using exceptions for control flow, which is what the `if` was for in the first place.

Comment: @David This is what I thought. The code is just to connect to the database but used to create users for my website. I thought that not being able to connect would not be the user (clients) fault as it doesn't exist on the server side.

Comment: @JLi_2398: When considering 4xx codes, ask yourself... "Is there anything the user can do to modify their request to correct the problem?"  In this case the answer would appear to be no.  Some file used server-side may not exist, but that's not the file being requested by the user.

Comment: @David: I use these exceptions as this file that the code belongs to is used for an ajax request, which I use to display the correct response on the website depending on the response returned. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 5xx status code would be appropriate here.  503 or 500 both seem reasonable, depending on how expected vs. unexpected you consider this particular error to be.

404 means that the user requested a resource that doesn't exist.  Did they in this case?  Some supporting back-end service may not exist or may be failing, but that's not the user's concern.  The HTTP status codes refer to the HTTP resources, not to your back-end infrastructure.  And the user requested the correct resource.

When returning any 4xx status code, ask yourself:

> Is there anything the user can do to modify their request to correct the problem?

If the answer is no then it's not a client error, it's a server error.  Which puts the problem in 5xx territory.

---

As an aside, this looks like a poor use of exceptions:

```
if (!file_exists("dbConn.php")) {
    throw new Exception("File Not Found");
} else {
    //...
}
```

This is basically using exceptions for control flow, which is what the `if` was already for.  You've already determined in an `if` condition that the file you're looking for is not available.  Within the `if` block you can craft your response and end execution of the script.

So potentially something like:

```
if (!file_exists("dbConn.php")) {
    http_response_code(500);
    die 'Unable to process the request.';
}
// No need for an "else" here, just continue as normal
```

This sort of thing is often called a "guard clause".  At the beginning of your overall operation you check your preconditions and fail if necessary.  If all guard clauses pass, the code is safe to continue.